# Correct way to create a editable component fetching data from server?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component called `EditProfile` where the user can update the info of their profile. Below is simplified version of component.

```
class EditProfile extends Component {
  state = {
    editable: false,

    //main form data goes below here
    username: "",
    fullname: "",
    country: "",
    gender: "",
    description: "",

  };
  setGender = e => {
    this.setState({ gender: e.target.value });
  };

  onInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({ errors: {} });
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };


  static getDerivedStateFromProps = (nextProps, prevState) => {
    if (nextProps.profile.username !== prevState.username) {
      return { username: nextProps.profile.username };
    }
  };
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="ProfileSignUp">
        <h2 className="ProfileSignUp__header">Personal Information</h2>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="ProfileSignUp__username"
          placeholder="Username"
          name="username"
          value={this.state.username}
          onChange={this.onInputChange}
        />
        {this.state.errors.username}
        <input
          type="text"
          className="ProfileSignUp__fullname"
          placeholder="Fullname"
          name="fullname"
          value={this.state.fullname}
          onChange={this.onInputChange}
        />
        {this.state.errors.fullname}
        <div className="ProfileSignUp__save-btn" onClick={this.saveProfile}>
          Save Profile
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  profile: state.profile
});
```

As you can see the value on state is set from `getDerivedStateFromProps`.I want to wait till the `profile` is received from server in `mapStateToProps`.After that I want to update the value in state with the props from `profile`.Once that is done I want to switch to `editable` mode. The program should not care about the props and I can freely update the value in state. But with the current way the value in state is set correctly once the data is received from the server but I cannot update it. Can anyone suggest me correct pattern to do that?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: @AkshayAggarwal Thanks for you solution. But I figured out it

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this. You can do something like this in `getDerivedStateFromProps`

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps = (nextProps, prevState) => {
    //After the data is fetched once from the server
    //editable is set to true and this function never runs
    //It just sets the value of state from props one time
    if (
      nextProps.profile &&
      nextProps.profile.loggedIn &&
      !prevState.editable
    ) {
      return {
        username: nextProps.profile.username,
        fullname: nextProps.profile.fullname,
        gender: nextProps.profile.gender,
        description: nextProps.profile.description,
        userImage: nextProps.profile.userImage,
        editable: true
      };
    }
  };
```